# What would consider a good practice to log CAN physical layer?

Tags: can, datalogger

We have a CANBUS line and we try to understand different causes for problems. We already logging the CAN from CAN frame perspective. But we would to log electronic events on the CAN line itself.
Events like : voltage spikes, current and etc..

What we would be the best practice to do it. Note that we cannot just connect scope as this line on a moving vehicle and we want to log information near events of CAN faults. Maybe to record 30 seconds in a cyclic mode and then save it only when there is a CAN error?

Comment: Use a CANbus analyser --> https://uk.farnell.com/microchip/apgdt002/can-bus-analyzer-tool-can-2-0b/dp/1800556?CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-KWL-MAN-L5Pages-New-Structure-CatchAll-Test991&gclid=CjwKCAjwl6OiBhA2EiwAuUwWZVp03TE3iGEvxLb6W4nUlt-wtwCATmEFelU8BnXgYWDUh3xoghuzSBoCAKEQAvD_BwE

Comment: Try searching the web: [CAN bus analyzer tool](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=can+bus+analyzer+tool&t=opera&ia=web).

Comment: The normal definition of a CAN bus analyser is a _CAN listener_, which is _not_ what the OP needs in this case. Such a tool can only log error frames at best, not low level signal problems. The tool the OP is looking for is known as an oscilloscope.

Comment: What about portable scope that can log?

Answer (score 1):

Many oscilloscopes have a feature to trig on digital pulses that are within certain intervals. If you configure one to trig on pulses that are 6x your bit length (+/- some marigin), then you have configured it to trigger on error frames. If you connect the scope to CANH then recessive bits are at 2.5V and dominant at 3.5V. An error frame is a sequence of 6 bits at 3.5V. So you'd set the trigger at 3V something, trigger on rising edge. Expect the error condition to be present on the signal just before the error frame.

Now I noted that you say you can't use a scope... so tough luck... You'll have to find some portable logger with the same abilities. It needs to sample quick enough to keep up with your bit rate and in my experience most such loggers only support down to ms accuracy, which won't do in this case.

Comment: Portable logger with scope abilities this probably what I should look for

Comment: @oak Fluke have some portable scopes with logging possibilities that are reasonably rugged, although I can't say I have good experience from using them. Mine is some 15 years old by now though so maybe they have improved.